# Python - sum of each day in multiple excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a excel sheets data like below,

Sheet1

```
duration date
10      5/20/2017 08:20 
23      5/20/2017 10:20
33      5/21/2017 12:20
56      5/22/2017 23:20
```

Sheet2

```
duration date
34      5/20/2017 01:20 
12      5/20/2017 03:20
05      5/21/2017 11:20
44      5/22/2017 23:20
```

Expected OP :

```
day[20] : [33, 46]
day[21] : [33, 12]
day[22] : [56, 44]
```

I am trying to sum of duration day wise in all sheets like below code,

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('reports.xlsx')
    report_sheets = []
    for sheetName in xls.sheet_names:
        sheet = pd.read_excel(xls,sheet_name=sheetName)
        sheet['date'] = pd.to_datetime(sheet['date'])
        print(sheet.groupby(sheet['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['duration'].sum().sort_values())
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Should't `day[20] : [33, 46]` be `day[20] : [10, 23, 34, 12]`? I got confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter `sheet_name=False` to [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for return `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('reports.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
print (dfs)
OrderedDict([('Sheet1',    duration             date
0        10  5/20/2017 08:20
1        23  5/20/2017 10:20
2        33  5/21/2017 12:20
3        56  5/22/2017 23:20), ('Sheet2',    duration             date
0        34  5/20/2017 01:20
1        12  5/20/2017 03:20
2         5  5/21/2017 11:20
3        44  5/22/2017 23:20)])
```

Then aggregate in dictionary comprehension:

```
dfs1 = {i:x.groupby(pd.to_datetime(x['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['duration'].sum() for i, x in dfs.items()}
print (dfs1)
{'Sheet2': date
2017-05-20    46
2017-05-21     5
2017-05-22    44
Name: duration, dtype: int64, 'Sheet1': date
2017-05-20    33
2017-05-21    33
2017-05-22    56
Name: duration, dtype: int64}
```

And last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), create `list`s and last dictionary by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = pd.concat(dfs1).groupby(level=1).apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{'2017-05-22': [56, 44], '2017-05-21': [33, 5], '2017-05-20': [33, 46]}
```

Comment: dfs1 is saying "mismatched input 'for' expecting RCURLY
mismatched input 'i' expecting NEWLINE
no viable alternative at input '}' ". why?

Comment: @MMMMS - It seems some data problem, data are confidental?

Comment: dfs = pd.read_excel('C:\\ff1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
    print(dfs)
    dfs1 = {i:x.groupby(pd.to_datetime(x['date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['duration'].sum() for i, x in dfs.items()}
    print (dfs1)
    d = pd.concat(dfs1).groupby(level=1).apply(list).to_dict()

Comment: I tried above but it saying "no viable alternative at input 'for'

mismatched input 'for' expecting RCURLY

mismatched input 'for' expecting RCURLY

mismatched input 'i' expecting NEWLINE

no viable alternative at input '}' " in that dfs1

Comment: @MMMMS - hmmm, what is your pandas version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167395/discussion-between-mmmms-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that takes the sheet's dataframe and returns a dictionary

```
def make_goofy_dict(d):
    d = d.set_index('date').duration.resample('D').sum()
    return d.apply(lambda x: [x]).to_dict()
```

Then use `merge_with` from either `toolz` or `cytoolz`

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge_with

merge_with(lambda x: sum(x, []), map(make_goofy_dict, (sheet1, sheet2)))

{Timestamp('2017-05-20 00:00:00', freq='D'): [33, 46],
 Timestamp('2017-05-21 00:00:00', freq='D'): [33, 5],
 Timestamp('2017-05-22 00:00:00', freq='D'): [56, 44]}
```

---

**details**

```
print(sheet1, sheet2, sep='\n\n')

   duration                date
0        10 2017-05-20 08:20:00
1        23 2017-05-20 10:20:00
2        33 2017-05-21 12:20:00
3        56 2017-05-22 23:20:00

   duration                date
0        34 2017-05-20 01:20:00
1        12 2017-05-20 03:20:00
2         5 2017-05-21 11:20:00
3        44 2017-05-22 23:20:00
```

---

**For your problem**
I'd do this

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge_with


def make_goofy_dict(d):
    d = d.set_index('date').duration.resample('D').sum()
    return d.apply(lambda x: [x]).to_dict()

def read_sheet(xls, sn):
    return pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sn, parse_dates=['date'])


xls = pd.ExcelFile('reports.xlsx')

sheet_dict = merge_with(
    lambda x: sum(x, []),
    map(make_goofy_dict, map(read_sheet, xls.sheet_names))
)
```